# Redirect from one domain to another but only to the index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect all links from an old domain to a new site but have all the links land on the home page only.
I am using the following but links such as `http://www.myoldside.com/index.php?route=movies` route to `http://www.mynewdomain/index.php?route=movies`.

What I would like is for all links to land at `http://www.mynewdomain/index.php`

This is my code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myoldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http://www.newdomain.com/index.php" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) - add `${QUERY_STRING}` to the new location..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to quote the target URL and add `?` in the end to strip-off any query string attached with old URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myoldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com/index.php? [R=301,L]
```

Also there is no need to capture the old URI using `(.*)` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I'll forward my resume to the above email-address. `Are you open to move to other locations?` ya..